# Weapon level damage difference?

Tags: death-rally-2012

Is there a big difference in damage from level to level when upgrading weapons in Death Rally 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example strikers at level 1 will launch 3 missiles, when reaching level 9 you will launch about 10 missiles that will cause much more damages :)

The flame thrower with each level up will burn other cars much far away.